# Is it possible to implement BCS with SharePoint online and External DB oracle?

Tags: sharepoint

We want to get the data from an external DB server(Oracle) and add it to our list in SharePoint online(SP-O). Is it possible to do it using BCS? If yes then please give me some tips for that.
Ex: I want to display data to a SP-O list from a database of my local machine/any other server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the resolution of it. I just followed below steps:

1. Implement a WCF/REST web service to fetch data from DB server. Follow this blog to create a REST service: [Create WCF REST Service.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571813/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Creating-WCF-REST-Services)
2. Create an External Content Type using SharePoint designer. Select WCF Service as a data source while adding a connection. Follow this blog to cretae an External Content Type using WCF Service. [BCS to create ECT using WCF service as a data source.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff953200(v=office.14).aspx)
3. Create a list using the External Content Type.

**Note:**  SharePoit site and WCF service must be hosted on same protocol, either on **http** or **https**. Otherwise it will give an access denied error.